# Decomposition of Determinant of Sub-Matrices of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $\bf A$ over a field. Let $\bf A$ is constructed by the product of $n \times n$ matrices $B_i$, for $1\leq i \leq m$ which means 
$$
{\bf A}=\prod_{i=1}^m\, {\bf B}_i\, .
$$
From Linear Algebra we know that the relation between determinant of $\bf A$ and $\bf B_i$'s are as follows:
$$
{\det(\bf A)}=\prod_{i=1}^m\, {\det(\bf B}_i)\, .
$$
Suppose that an $k \times k$ sub-matrix of $\bf A$ for $1\leq k \leq n$  is denoted with ${\bf A}^{(k)}$.

**My question:** Is there a relation between determinant of ${\bf A}^{(k)}$ and determinants of $\bf B_i$'s.

In fact, I want to ask this question: Is there a condition that can be used to check  ${\bf A}^{(k)}$ is singular or non-singular matrix based on the determinants of $\bf B_i$'s or sub-matrices of $\bf B_i$'s.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: There is the Cauchy-Binet formula, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-Binet_formula. Say that $I$ is a subset of $k$ rows and $J$ is a subset of $k$ columns of $A$, and $A_{I,J}$ is the submatrix with those rows and columns. Then $\det A_{I,J} = \sum \det B_{1,I,K_1} \det B_{2,K_1,K_2} \dotsm \det B_{m,K_{m-1},J}$ where the sum is over every possible choice of $k$-element sets $K_1,\dotsc,K_{m-1}$, and $B_{i,K_{i-1},K_i}$ means the submatrix of $B_i$ with rows $K_{i-1}$ and columns $K_i$. So, that is a relation between the determinants. But it's not a clear condition for singularity, sorry.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thanks for your comment. It is a useful reference that you pointed it.